# jQuery selector first td of each row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this stuff:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>nonono</td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
    </td>foobar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nonono2</td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
    </td>foobar2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>nonono3</td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
    </td>foobar2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried with `$('td:first')` with no luck;

Expected return: `<td>nonono</td>`, `<td>nonon2</td>` and `<td>nonon3</td>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/): *"The `:first` pseudo-class is equivalent to `:eq(0)`. It could also be written as `:lt(1)`. While this matches only a single element, `:first-child` can match more than one: One for each parent."*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should use `:first-child` instead of `:first`:

Sounds like you're wanting to iterate through them. You can do this using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Example:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Result:

```
nonono
nonono2
nonono3
```

Alernatively if you're not wanting to iterate:

```
$('td:first-child').css('background', '#000');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Hxq/).

Comment: I will accept as correct answer because the alternatively method contais `:first-child`

Answer (score 17):

try this selector -

```
$("tr").find("td:first")
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/66HbV/

Or

```
$("tr td:first-child")
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/66HbV/1/

`</td>foobar</td>` should be `<td>foobar</td>`

Comment: Just use `first-child`. The reason `:first` doesn't work alone is because it's pulling the very first element and nothing more.

Comment: This did it for me. When you are looking for the only one selected I used: `$(this).find("td:first")`

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this

```js
$(function(){
  $("tr").find("td:eq(0)").css("color","red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var tablefirstcolumn=$("tr").find("td:first")
alert(tablefirstcolumn+"of Each row")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$("tr").find("td:first");
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LV9Dj/) - this example has [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on the end to show that it is returning the elements.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$("td:first-child");
```

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var children = null;
$('tr').each(function(){
    var td = $(this).children('td:first');
    if(children == null)
        children = td;
    else
        children.add(td);
});

// children should now hold all the first td elements
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('td:first-child')` will return a collection of the elements that you want.

```
var text = $('td:first-child').map(function() {
  return $(this).html();
}).get();
```